# Install PECL SSH2 extension for PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I am trying to install this
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php
on a Centos 5 (a fork of RHEL 5).

I installed libssh2 (yum install libssh2) which is located in /usr/lib, and when I install SSH2 extension (via pecl install -f ssh2) I get this message

> checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found
> configure: error: The required libssh2 library was not found.  You can obtain that package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libssh2/
> ERROR: `/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-0.11.0/configure --with-ssh2=/usr' failed

If I set /usr/lib, I get the same message

> ERROR: `/tmp/pear/download/ssh2-0.11.0/configure --with-ssh2=/usr/lib' failed

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Installing libssh2 via tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libssh2/ help a lot (--with-ssh2=/usr/local/include/).

But :

```
yum install libssh2-devel
```

...is a better idea.

Comment: What repository are you getting that from? I can't find it in the default or in Atomic.

Comment: Don't we need `pecl install` as well?

Comment: No need for PECL for this installation, but you may have another solution.

Comment: That made life easier. Thanks!

After installing libssh2-devel you can "pecl install ssh-1.1.2" or whatever recent version and it'll work.

EDIT: did not realize this was a 2009 threadn still works though. :P

Comment: these codes are for CentOS and possibly for MAC.

Does it work for Ubuntu?

replacing yum with apt-get ???

Answer (score 11):

```
$ sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
$ sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
$ sudo pecl install -a ssh2-0.12
$ echo 'extension=ssh2.so' | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/ssh2.ini > /dev/null
$ sudo php5enmod ssh2
```

Comment: Worked well on a Ubuntu box on Vagrant.

Comment: If your Vagrant box is running php 7, `sudo pecl install -a ssh2-1.0` as per [their documentation](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

Comment: I followed the instruction and the modules are available when I run php through apache. But not when I run php from command line. What would you do at this point?

Answer (score 3):

This is updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381432/2604320) from @serghei + modification from @avn from comment under working solution for **PHP 7.x**.

```
$ sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
$ sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
$ sudo pecl install -a ssh2-1.0
$ echo 'extension=ssh2.so' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ssh2.ini > /dev/null
$ sudo phpenmod ssh2
```

Regarding line:

```
echo 'extension=ssh2.so' | sudo tee /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ssh2.ini > /dev/null
```

Make sure that path `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available` is valid and there is a match with your php version.

Answer (score 2):

`yum install libssh2-devel` didn't work for me:

No package libssh2-devel available.

So I downloaded rpm package from [rpmfind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libssh2-devel) and installed with `rpm -ivh`

After that just added `extension=ssh2.so` to `/etc/php.d/ssh2.ini`

Answer (score 1):

I'm running on Centos, none of these answer  were the entire solution for me. I followed [these instructions](http://blog.dynamichosting.biz/2011/01/10/installing-ssh2-extension-for-php-on-centos-5/):

```
$ sudo yum install -y gcc php-devel php-pear libssh2 libssh2-devel
```

But `php-devel` would not install, complaining about conflicts. I searched yum to find what php devel packages I had available

```
$> yum search php|grep devel
...
php55u-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php56u-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php70u-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
...
```

So I ran

```
$> sudo yum install -y php56u-devel
```

And it installed cleanly. Then, continuing with the instructions, I ran

```
$ pecl install -f ssh2
```

And it compiled. Then I added the extension to php

```
$ touch /etc/php.d/ssh2.ini
$ echo extension=ssh2.so > /etc/php.d/ssh2.ini
```

And on my system, instead of

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

I had to do

```
$ sudo /bin/systemctl restart  php-fpm.service
```

So that was all the steps to install. And finally to confirm:

```
$> php -m|grep ssh2
ssh2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem:

I'm on a Pair.com "Advanced" hosted account, so I'm a little limited on what I'm allowed to do.  I don't think I can `yum` nor `aptitude` nor any of the other pre-compiled packages.

I've downloaded and compiled libssh2.  During the `pecl` process, it asks where the library is located.  It's in "~/usr/local/lib" and I've tried several variations, including fully qualified.  But I kept getting the same error.

The error message doesn't spell out precisely which file it's looking for.  libssh2.so is in that directory.  I know the output is supposed to be ssh2.so.  I wondered if there is supposed to be an ss2.something, or libssh.nothing?

I fixed it thus. In my case, after compiling libssh2 I downloaded the PEAR tarball.  The trick was:

```
./configure --with-ssh2=<libssh2 location> --prefix=<libssh2 location>
```

Another trick is that, since Pair.com is running FreeBSD, I have to do a "cd ." after the ./configure command.  Otherwise, make produces a "Permission denied" error.  Apparently, this is necessary on all *nix BSD flavors.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found
configure: error: The required libssh2 library was not found.
```

...can be seen in [the source code](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/networking/ssh2.git;a=blob;f=config.m4;h=c6b5354b1f4ac542a3068d418a58d77de5e22b33;hb=HEAD#l23).

The logic in the code reveals that it will throw this error if it cannot find `/include/libssh2.h` in either `/usr/local`, `/usr` or in the path supplied by the optional  `--with-ssh2=[DIR]` directive. In other words, without customising the directive, it needs to find one of the following:

```
/usr/local/include/libssh2.h
/usr/include/libssh2.h
```

If it passes this check, it then assumes it can find the libssh2 `lib` at `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`.

Hopefully the info above is enough to help someone debug their issue. My own case is fairly specific and unusual (macOS with Homebrew in a custom install path), but in case it helps anyone else, here's my horrifically hacky workaround. Works perfectly lol

In a nutshell I'm creating two temporary symlinks so that pecl can find ssh2 where it expects.

```sh
# First check that neither /usr/local/include nor /usr/local/lib exists

sudo ln -s /usr/local/CustomInstallPath/Homebrew/Cellar/libssh2/1.9.0_1/include /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s /usr/local/CustomInstallPath/Homebrew/Cellar/libssh2/1.9.0_1/lib /usr/local/lib
pecl install -a ssh2-1.3.1
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib
```