# Install ssh2 extension having homebrew and php 7.3

Tags: homebrew, pecl, libssh2, php-7.3, ssh2

I am facing the following error while trying to install `ssh2` extension with pecl:

```
17 warnings and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [ssh2_fopen_wrappers.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Here is what I've done:

```
brew install php
brew install libssh2
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

That installed php 7.3.3, libssh2 1.8.0 and failed to install ssh2-1.1.2.
Does anyone have a solution for the problem? Thank you!

Related links:
https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/767
[Install PECL SSH2 extension for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561024/install-pecl-ssh2-extension-for-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My original answer: [SSH2 for PHP7 MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886490/ssh2-for-php7-macos/57280595)

I finally found a solution on MacOS Mohave. I have PHP 7.3 installed by Homebrew:

```
brew install php
brew install libssh2
```

Install development version of ssh2 pecl extension from the latest sources:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-ssh2.git
cd pecl-networking-ssh2
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Enable extension in `php.ini`. You can use TextEdit:

```
open -e /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
```

Add `extension="ssh2.so"` to the beginning of the file and save.

Test the result:

```
php -i | grep 'libssh2 version'
```

You should see

```
libssh2 version => 1.10.0
```

**-- EDIT for Apple silicon (M1)**

Homebrew uses different path on Apple silicon machines and ./configure command fails with error: "checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found". I resolved this with setting custom path:

```
./configure --with-ssh2=/opt/homebrew/opt/libssh2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `libssh2-1-dev`

```
brew install libssh2-1-dev
```

Update pecl

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

And then install `ssh2-1.1.2`

```
brew install ssh2-1.1.2
```

This is how it worked for me

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I don't have apt-get as I use Mac OS.

Comment: Then use brew and install `libssh2-1-dev`

Comment: There is no such formula in brew, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case I suggest to take the tar from their website and compile the files yourself.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1089390/how-to-install-libssl-dev-libffi-dev-on-mac-os

Comment: You mean `pecl install ssh2-1.1.2`

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install libssh2
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this is called gate keeping.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this answer about docker](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/767#issuecomment-450726988)

```sh
brew install libssh2-1-dev

cd /tmp && git clone https://git.php.net/repository/pecl/networking/ssh2.git && cd /tmp/ssh2

phpize && ./configure && make && make install


echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-ssh2.ini

rm -rf /tmp/ssh2
```